# Website deployed in IIS does not cache any thing in browser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, hosting, web-deployment

> I have MVC4 web application that cache every thing in my local machine but does not cache any thing when deployed under IIS8 except fav icon.

What could be the possible reason for the same?

Comment: What do you mean by no caching? Do you mean server side caching or client side caching? How do you know that caching is not happening?

Comment: @AlexC client side  caching as no file are stored in cache folder( ofIE)